# MYSQL condense group by two columns into group by one column with breakdown

Tags: mysql

I am trying to condense an order by 2 columns query, into an order by 1 column query with a breakdown column. If this has a proper name I would greatly appreciate knowing what it is!

Example:

```
ocean
name     | type    | colour
fishy    | salmon  | red
splishy  | salmon  | red
splashy  | salmon  | pink
sploshy  | salmon  | pink
floaty   | whale   | blue
humprhey | whale   | grey
wilson   | whale   | grey
```

Looking for *(I'm not sure what doing this is called)*:

```
type  | count | colour breakdown
salmon| 4     | 2 red, 2 pink
whale | 3     | 1 blue, 2 grey
```

Preferentially with minimal use of string functions.

---

Not sure how to proceed from:

(Order by one column)

```
SELECT o.type, count(*)
FROM ocean o
GROUP BY `type`

type  | count
salmon| 4
whale | 3
```

(Order by two columns)

```
SELECT o.type, o.colour, count(*)
FROM ocean o
GROUP BY `type`, `colour`

type  | colour     | count
salmon| red        | 2
salmon| pink       | 2
whale | blue       | 1
whale | grey       | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugly, untested, but may just do what you want:

```
SELECT type, SUM(color_count),
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(color_count, ' ', colour) SEPARATOR ', ') AS colour_breakdown
FROM (
    SELECT type, colour, COUNT(colour) AS colour_count
    FROM ocean
    GROUP BY type, colour
) AS subt
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your second query as a data source, you can use `group_concat()` to get the output you want:

```
select type, sum(`count`), group_concat(colBreak separator ',') as color_breakdown
from
    (
        SELECT 
            o.type, 
            o.colour, 
            count(o.type) as `count`, 
            concat(o.colour, ' ', count(o.type)) as colBreak
        FROM ocean o 
        GROUP BY `type`, `colour`
    ) as a
group by type;
```

Comment: For me I needed to add "as count" to "count(o.type)", I might have broke it whilst translating to my actual DB structure (I'm not a marine countologist). Thank you!